# Why apps stays in memory after program stop running?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

When I'm debugging apps on my Nexus-5 device (which use Android operating system) with the Android Studio, then after clicking the red 'Stop' button, the application's panel is vanish from the device screen, but if I click on the squere "Recent" button on the bottom android's bar (which have 3 buttons: Triangle arrow="Back", Circle="Home", Square="Recent") then it shows me that my app is still running in the background... why is that?

Why clicking on the Android Studio 'Stop' button is not enough to stop the application's running on my device?

Comment: Start by learning more about an `Android activity's lifecycle`: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: OK I understand... I know that it's says: "Recent" but still it reminded me the double-click mechanism that I have on my iPhone that shows me all the applications currently running on my device and let me close them by dragging them up, so I assumed that in the Android it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

> but if I click on the squere "Recent" button on the bottom android's bar... then it shows me that my app is still running in the background

No, it does not. That brings up the overview screen, showing recent tasks. "Recent" != "running". Apps shown in the overview screen may or may not have running processes.

> Why clicking on the Android Studio 'Stop' button is not enough to stop the application's running on my device?

It is enough. It does not remove the task from the recent-tasks list, just as closing a tab in a Web browser does not delete a bookmark.

Comment: OK I understand... yeah I know that it's says: "Recent" but still it reminded me the double-click mechanism that I have on my iPhone that shows me all the applications currently running on my device and let me close them by dragging them up, so I assumed that in the Android it's the same.